# Multiple hostnames for a single IP address in local network

Tags: networking, alias, hostname

I'd like to know if it is possible to have multiple hostnames for a single IP address in my local network, so that all hostnames point to the same IP-address (kind of an alias)

```
Example:

name           IP address

server1        192.168.1.10
client1        192.168.1.10
```

of course I could enter both names in /etc/hosts, but then the other names would not be known in the whole local network.

Is this possible and if yes, how would I do that?

Thanx a lot for your help,

Rudi

Comment: Have you already local DNS resolution? If yes, could you add that information to the question, stating which one? If you haven't set it up, then that would be your first step, and then I don't think the mapping of hosts to single address would be an issue.

Comment: Hi Eduardo

thanks for your answer. Until now I don't have a local DNS resolver and I was hoping for an easier solution. Is there another way of achieving my desired result? Or is this the only way?

Comment: You could make sure that each machine had the same /etc/hosts file, but that's the sort of PITA jerry-rigged BS that DNS was created to avoid.   Setting up a DNS server isn't particularly hard, and (IMO) every network should have at least its own caching resolver and (optionally) an authoritative server for local hostnames. [dnsmasq](https://thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html) is simple and popular and well-documented (and optionally provides dhcp service as well as both authoritative and caching dns).  Other alternatives include `unbound` for caching dns and `nsd` for authoritative.